# Paragraph in longtable overfull

Tags: longtable, xfootnote

I am trying to write paragraphs in a `longtable` environment that describes some characteristics and applications of electromagnetics bands wave. So, with a first part, the code is fine, but in one part later it is not. (Attach some images and partial code without the header)

[image]

It works:

[image]

Could be better:

[image]

Although it does not yet, include a left part. Do you now in what part I have a mistake and how can I resolve it?

The code is below. The colors `M4` and `bl` previously has been defined with `\etal`, `\y` and others.

```
\begin{longtable}{p{25mm}p{70mm}|p{65mm}}
\caption{Generalidades das bandas espectrais. Retirado e adaptado de: como é indicado} \\ 
%\label{tab:mat-gen_ban}
%\begin{tabular}

\rowcolor{m4} \textcolor{bl}{Banda espectral} & \textcolor{bl}{Característica} & \textcolor{bl}{Aplicação}  \tabularnewline%
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
\rowcolor{m4} \textcolor{bl}{Banda espectral} & \textcolor{bl}{Característica} & \textcolor{bl}{Aplicação}  \tabularnewline%
    \endhead
 %
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textcolor{bl}{\cellcolor{m4} Continua a tabela}} 
\endfoot %
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textcolor{bl}{\cellcolor{m4} Final da tabela}} 
\endlastfoot  % 

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Apesar de que sua energia pode estar a ser de $1MeV$, mais de $100TeV$ e baixos comprimentos de onda (abaixo de us $10^{-3}nm$\footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontes, 2005}, a grande maioria é aprisionada pela atmosfera terrestre na ionosfera e uma pequena parte atinge a superfície terrestre. Dentro das fontes de sua emissão, estão as supernovas, pulsares, Estrelas de nêutrons, núcleos galácticos ativos, buracos negros, explosões nucleares e aquelas que redundam na desintegração nuclear\footnote{García, 2021; Orienti, 2016; Fontal, 2005}.}  & 
 Estudo e objetos do universo (Luongo \y Muccino, 2021; Téllez, 2021; Orienti, 2016). \\ \cline{3-3}
 &  &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\   \cline{3-3}  
   &  & Medicina nuclear e radioterapia. (Mackenney \etal 2020; Lovo \etal 2017; Zeferino \etal 2011). \\ \cline{3-3}   
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Raios Gamma}   &  & Indução de mutações em espécies vegetais (Gómez \etal 2020; Antúnez \etal 2017; Mayta, 2016). \\ \midrule

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Descobertos por Rötgen\footnote{Fonte, 2005} seus comprimentos de onda estão entre $10^{-3}nm$ a $10 nm$\footnote{Fuentes \etal 2015; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}, são produzidos quando elétrons ($e^{-}$) com uma energia tal alta penetra camadas  profundas e gera um efeito de deslocamento por o situado na parte mais superficial, até aquele em que a sua incidência foi menor. Essa mudança gerada pelo deslocamento de um elétron de um nível de energia maior para um menor, emite um fóton no comprimento de onda na banda correspondente aos raios X\footnote{Aponte de cátedra ,2017; Gonzáles, 2017}.}  & Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
 &  &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\   \cline{3-3}  
   &  & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}   
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Raios X}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). \\ \midrule



\multirow{1}{25mm}{UV}  & \multirow{1}{70mm}{Para alguns autores\footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, a banda inicia a partir de menos de $10nm$, enquanto que outros o fazem a partir de $100nm$\footnote{Moreira \etal 2020; Diffey, 2002} até $400nm$ e corresponde a $5\%$ do espectro que o sol emite. Os efeitos dérmicos que gera variam de acordo com seu comprimento de onda, e é por isso que de maneira genérica, subdivide-se tipicamente em 3 regiões (UVA, UVB e UVC). Ressalta que, a radiação UVC é absorvida pela atmosfera (especialmente a camada de ozônio) e esta não atinge a superfície\footnote{Mackenzie, 2020; Nishisaka, 2018; Diffey, 2002}. A radiação pode ocorrer naturalmente por estmulação elétrica em átomos e reações de fusão nuclear como ocorre no sol.}  & 
Identificação e melhoramento de compostos bioquímicos vegetais (Surjadinata \etal 2017; Pereira \etal 2015; Bravo \y Acuña, 2005). \vspace{2.5cm}\\ \cline{3-3} 

   &  &  Desinfecção e esterilização de patógenos  (López \y Apaza, 2020; Song \etal 2016; Bohrerova, 2008). \vspace{2.5cm} \\ \midrule      
 
     & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre 360$nm$ e $420nm$ até 780$nm$ \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a 6000 $K$ e o comprimento de onda é $0.5\mu m$ ou $500nm$\footnote{de Prada, 2016}} &  Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\  \cline{3-3} 
   & & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Visível}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015) \\ \midrule      

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre 360$nm$ e $420nm$ até 780$nm$ \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a 6000 $K$ e o comprimento de onda é $0.5\mu m$ ou $500nm$\footnote{de Prada, 2016}} &  Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \vspace{10mm}\\  \cline{3-3} 
   & & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \cline{3-3}
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Visível}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \midrule   

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{É a radiação que tem comprimentos de onda entre $700nm$ e $1\diez{-6}nm$ ($1mm$), e é produzida pela mudança no movimento rotacional ou vibratório dos componentes atômicos, e produz como reação no aumento da temperatura da matéria quando encontram um fluxo deste tipo \footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}} &  Inspeção de estruturas por métodos não destrutivos (Espiniza \y Fernat, 2021; Rodríguez, 2017). \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Estudo e correlação de variáveis ambientais como temperatura e umidade (Anaya, 2019; León \etal 2019; Matiz \etal 2019).\\  \cline{3-3} 
  \multirow{-3}{25mm}{Infravermelho}   &   & Soldar dispositivos eletrônicos com mais precisão e rapidez (Romo, 2021; Liebl \etal 2014; Gao \etal 2012). \\ \midrule      

%\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: it is very hard to debug a fragment please edit so the code is a complete small document that shows the problem

Comment: but multirow (if you use it) hides the vertical size of the entry and longtable can not catch that you may need to force a page break before that entry

Answer (score 0):

In relationship with an answer, here's a code adjusted only for the table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{booktabs}


\title{pruebas}
\author{pjruizr }
\date{November 2022}

%\definecolor{m-1}{HTML}{E6CFD5}
\definecolor{m1}{HTML}{D4003F}
\definecolor{m4}{HTML}{540019}
\definecolor{bl}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

\newcommand{\y}{$\&$}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et. al.}}
\newcommand{\diez}[1]{10^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{longtable}{p{25mm}p{70mm}|p{65mm}}
\caption{Generalidades das bandas espectrais. Retirado e adaptado de: como é indicado} \\
\rowcolor{m4} \textcolor{bl}{Banda espectral} & \textcolor{bl}{Característica} & \textcolor{bl}{Aplicação}  \tabularnewline%
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
\rowcolor{m4} \textcolor{bl}{Banda espectral} & \textcolor{bl}{Característica} & \textcolor{bl}{Aplicação}  \tabularnewline%
    \endhead
 %
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textcolor{bl}{\cellcolor{m4} Continua a tabela}} 
\endfoot %
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textcolor{bl}{\cellcolor{m4} Final da tabela}} 
\endlastfoot  % 

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Apesar de que sua energia pode estar a ser de $1MeV$, mais de $100TeV$ e baixos comprimentos de onda (abaixo de us $10^{-3}nm$\footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontes, 2005}, a grande maioria é aprisionada pela atmosfera terrestre na ionosfera e uma pequena parte atinge a superfície terrestre. Dentro das fontes de sua emissão, estão as supernovas, pulsares, Estrelas de nêutrons, núcleos galácticos ativos, buracos negros, explosões nucleares e aquelas que redundam na desintegração nuclear\footnote{García, 2021; Orienti, 2016; Fontal, 2005}.}  & 
 Estudo e objetos do universo (Luongo \y Muccino, 2021; Téllez, 2021; Orienti, 2016). \\ \cline{3-3}
 &  &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\   \cline{3-3}  
   &  & Medicina nuclear e radioterapia. (Mackenney \etal 2020; Lovo \etal 2017; Zeferino \etal 2011). \\ \cline{3-3}   
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Raios Gamma}   &  & Indução de mutações em espécies vegetais (Gómez \etal 2020; Antúnez \etal 2017; Mayta, 2016). \\ \midrule

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Descobertos por Rötgen\footnote{Fonte, 2005} seus comprimentos de onda estão entre $10^{-3}nm$ a $10 nm$\footnote{Fuentes \etal 2015; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}, são produzidos quando elétrons ($e^{-}$) com uma energia tal alta penetra camadas  profundas e gera um efeito de deslocamento por o situado na parte mais superficial, até aquele em que a sua incidência foi menor. Essa mudança gerada pelo deslocamento de um elétron de um nível de energia maior para um menor, emite um fóton no comprimento de onda na banda correspondente aos raios X\footnote{Aponte de cátedra ,2017; Gonzáles, 2017}.}  & Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
 &  &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\   \cline{3-3}  
   &  & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}   
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Raios X}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). \\ \midrule


\multirow{1}{25mm}{UV}  & \multirow{1}{70mm}{Para alguns autores\footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, a banda inicia a partir de menos de $10nm$, enquanto que outros o fazem a partir de $100nm$\footnote{Moreira \etal 2020; Diffey, 2002} até $400nm$ e corresponde a $5\%$ do espectro que o sol emite. Os efeitos dérmicos que gera variam de acordo com seu comprimento de onda, e é por isso que de maneira genérica, subdivide-se tipicamente em 3 regiões (UVA, UVB e UVC). Ressalta que, a radiação UVC é absorvida pela atmosfera (especialmente a camada de ozônio) e esta não atinge a superfície\footnote{Mackenzie, 2020; Nishisaka, 2018; Diffey, 2002}. A radiação pode ocorrer naturalmente por estmulação elétrica em átomos e reações de fusão nuclear como ocorre no sol.}  & 
Identificação e melhoramento de compostos bioquímicos vegetais (Surjadinata \etal 2017; Pereira \etal 2015; Bravo \y Acuña, 2005). \vspace{2.5cm}\\ \cline{3-3} 

   &  &  Desinfecção e esterilização de patógenos  (López \y Apaza, 2020; Song \etal 2016; Bohrerova, 2008). \vspace{2.5cm} \\ \midrule


 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre 360$nm$ e $420nm$ até 780$nm$ \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a 6000 $K$ e o comprimento de onda é $0.5\mu m$ ou $500nm$\footnote{de Prada, 2016}} &  Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \\  \cline{3-3} 
   & & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \\ \cline{3-3}
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Visível}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015) \\ \midrule
  

 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre 360$nm$ e $420nm$ até 780$nm$ \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a 6000 $K$ e o comprimento de onda é $0.5\mu m$ ou $500nm$\footnote{de Prada, 2016}} &  Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). \vspace{10mm}\\  \cline{3-3} 
   & & Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \cline{3-3}
\multirow{-4}{25mm}{Visível}   &  & Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). \vspace{10mm} \\ \midrule


 & \multirow{4}{70mm}{É a radiação que tem comprimentos de onda entre $700nm$ e $1\diez{-6}nm$ ($1mm$), e é produzida pela mudança no movimento rotacional ou vibratório dos componentes atômicos, e produz como reação no aumento da temperatura da matéria quando encontram um fluxo deste tipo \footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}} &  Inspeção de estruturas por métodos não destrutivos (Espiniza \y Fernat, 2021; Rodríguez, 2017). \\ \cline{3-3}
 & &  Estudo e correlação de variáveis ambientais como temperatura e umidade (Anaya, 2019; León \etal 2019; Matiz \etal 2019).\\  \cline{3-3} 
  \multirow{-3}{25mm}{Infravermelho}   &   & Soldar dispositivos eletrônicos com mais precisão e rapidez (Romo, 2021; Liebl \etal 2014; Gao \etal 2012). \\ \midrule



%\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: * This code, was created in Miktex with fast compilation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After while ...

For your table I would use `tabularray` package, for better cells content spacing `small` font size, use `siunitx` package for writing of quantities (by this is more evident if used quantities and units are correct, I suspect that some of them are not) and a wee bit redesign table style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{m1}{HTML}{D4003F}
\definecolor{m4}{HTML}{540019}
\definecolor{bl}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,
                siunitx}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et. al.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Generalidades das bandas espectrais. Retirado e adaptado de: como é indicado},
  label = {tab:mat-gen_ban}
                ]{hlines,
                  cells = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                  colspec = {X[0.25,l, cmd={\hskip 0pt}] X[j] X[j]},
                  colsep  = 3pt,
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, m, fg=bl, bg=m4},
                  vspan   = even,
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
Banda espectral &   Característica  &   Aplicação   \\
\SetCell[r=4]{m}    Raios Gamma
    &   \SetCell[r=4]{h}
        Apesar de que sua energia pode estar a ser de \qty{1}{MeV}, mais de \qty{100}{TeV} e baixos comprimentos de onda (abaixo de us \qty{E-3}{\nano\meter}\footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontes, 2005}, a grande maioria é aprisionada pela atmosfera terrestre na ionosfera e uma pequena parte atinge a superfície terrestre. Dentro das fontes de sua emissão, estão as supernovas, pulsares, Estrelas de nêutrons, núcleos galácticos ativos, buracos negros, explosões nucleares e aquelas que redundam na desintegração nuclear\footnote{García, 2021; Orienti, 2016; Fontal, 2005}.
        &   Estudo e objetos do universo (Luongo \& Muccino, 2021; Téllez, 2021; Orienti, 2016).       
        \\*
    &   &   Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016).
        \\* 
    &   &   Medicina nuclear e radioterapia. (Mackenney \etal 2020; Lovo \etal 2017; Zeferino \etal 2011).
        \\* 
    &   &   Indução de mutações em espécies vegetais (Gómez \etal 2020; Antúnez \etal 2017; Mayta, 2016). 
        \\
\SetCell[r=4]{m}    Raios X 
    &   \SetCell[r=4]{h}
        Descobertos por Rötgen\footnote{Fonte, 2005} seus comprimentos de onda estão entre \qty{E-3}{\nano\meter} a \qty{10}{\nano\meter}\footnote{Fuentes \etal 2015; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}, são produzidos quando elétrons ($e^{-}$) com uma energia tal alta penetra camadas  profundas e gera um efeito de deslocamento por o situado na parte mais superficial, até aquele em que a sua incidência foi menor. Essa mudança gerada pelo deslocamento de um elétron de um nível de energia maior para um menor, emite um fóton no comprimento de onda na banda correspondente aos raios X\footnote{Aponte de cátedra ,2017; Gonzáles, 2017}.  
        &   Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015).
            \\*
    &   &   Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). 
            \\*   
    &   &   Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). 
            \\* 
    &   &   Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). 
            \\
\SetCell[r=2]{m}    UV
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{h}
        Para alguns autores\footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, a banda inicia a partir de menos de $10nm$, enquanto que outros o fazem a partir de \qty{100}{\nano\meter}\footnote{Moreira \etal 2020; Diffey, 2002} até $400nm$ e corresponde a \qty{5}{\%} do espectro que o sol emite. Os efeitos dérmicos que gera variam de acordo com seu comprimento de onda, e é por isso que de maneira genérica, subdivide-se tipicamente em 3 regiões (UVA, UVB e UVC). Ressalta que, a radiação UVC é absorvida pela atmosfera (especialmente a camada de ozônio) e esta não atinge a superfície\footnote{Mackenzie, 2020; Nishisaka, 2018; Diffey, 2002}. A radiação pode ocorrer naturalmente por estmulação elétrica em átomos e reações de fusão nuclear como ocorre no sol.
        &   Identificação e melhoramento de compostos bioquímicos vegetais (Surjadinata \etal 2017; Pereira \etal 2015; Bravo \& Acuña, 2005).
        \\*
   &    &   Desinfecção e esterilização de patógenos  (López \& Apaza, 2020; Song \etal 2016; Bohrerova, 2008).
        \\
\SetCell[r=4]{m}    Visível
    &   \SetCell[r=4]{h}
        Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre \qty{360}{\nano\meter} e \qty{42}{\nano\meter} até \qty{780}{\nano\meter} \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a \qty{6000}{\kelvin} e o comprimento de onda é \qty{0.5}{\micro\meter} ou \qty{500}{\nano\meter}\footnote{de Prada, 2016}
        &   Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). 
            \\*
    &   &   Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). 
            \\*
    &   &   Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). 
            \\*
    &   &   Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015) 
            \\
\SetCell[r=4]{m}    Visível
    &   \SetCell[r=4]{h}
        Compreende os comprimentos de onda entre 360$nm$ e $420nm$ até 780$nm$ \footnote{Herrera \etal, 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fuentes, 2005}, cuja interação com o olho humano permite identificar a cor como o resultado da reflectância de um comprimento determinado, sendo a mais baixa violeta e a mais alta associada ao vermelho. Quando um corpo reflete todas as ondas desta faixa, a cor que se visualiza é branco \footnote{Rocha, 2020} e caso contrário (quando são absorvidas) é preto. O comprimento de onda da cor que um corpo emite tem relação inversa com a temperatura absoluta que se encontra de acordo com a Lei de Wien, e a partir disso, foi possível estimar a temperatura de corpos celestes como o sol cuja magnitude é próximo a 6000 $K$ e o comprimento de onda é \qty{0.5}{\micro\meter} ou \qty{500}{\nano\meter}\footnote{de Prada, 2016}
        &   Caracterização de nanomateriais e estruturas atômicas (Susi \etal 2015). 
            \\* 
    &   &   Observação de buracos negros, pulsares, remanescentes de supernovas e análise de estruturas de plasma (entre outros) (Zhang \etal 2020; Sibeck \etal 2018; Barret \etal 2016). 
            \\*
    &   &   Diagnóstico, análise e tratamento de doenças (Nazia \etal 2020; Haume \etal 2016; Fuentes \etal 2015). 
            \\*
    &   &   Gestão e conservação de bens agrícolas (Gatullo \etal 2020; Guzmán \etal 2019; Díaz, 2015). 
            \\
\SetCell[r=3]{m}    Infravermelho
    &   \SetCell[r=3]{h}    
        É a radiação que tem comprimentos de onda entre \qty{700}{\nano\meter} e \qty{E-6}{\meter} (\qty{1}{\micro\meter}), e é produzida pela mudança no movimento rotacional ou vibratório dos componentes atômicos, e produz como reação no aumento da temperatura da matéria quando encontram um fluxo deste tipo \footnote{Herrera \etal 2018; Alzate, 2007; Fontal, 2005}.
        &   Inspeção de estruturas por métodos não destrutivos (Espiniza \& Fernat, 2021; Rodríguez, 2017). 
            \\*
    &   &  Estudo e correlação de variáveis ambientais como temperatura e umidade (Anaya, 2019; León \etal 2019; Matiz \etal 2019).\\  \cline{3-3}
    &   &   Soldar dispositivos eletrônicos com mais precisão e rapidez (Romo, 2021; Liebl \etal 2014; Gao \etal 2012). 
            \\ 
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```